# Binded click event firing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function called `getMedia()` which fires an `ajax` call to get some content. I also have some filters at the top and `onclick` I've binded an even to destory the content grid and fetch new content but it is firing off when the document loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var numposts = $(".social__board").data('numposts');
   $.each(accounts, function(key, value) {
       getMedia(".board", key, value, numposts);
   });
   setGridFilter(".filters", ".board", ".grid-item");
});
```

and then in the same file I have the `setGridFilter` function.

```
function setGridFilter(filters, board, griditem) {
$(filters + " li").first().addClass("active");
$(document).on("click", $(filters + " li"), function(){
    $(griditem).remove();
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().removeClass("active");
    var source = $(this).data("source");
    var numposts = $(board).data('numposts') * 3; // MORE POSTS FOR SINGLE CHANNEL
    var username = $(board).attr("data-" + source);
    console.log("Source: " + source + "Numposts: " + numposts + "Username" + username);
    getMedia(board, source, username, numposts);
});
}
```

Comment: why are you passing selector as a DOM element? replace ` $(filters + " li")` with `filters + " li" `

Comment: `$(document).on("click", $(filters + " li"), function(){` should be `$(document).on("click", filters + " li", function(){`